# Java / MySQL and JSON_SET array not working

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am using MySQL / JSON to store userdata in the database. I have one userid column and a column named data. The data column is a json type.

The default value of this json column is "{}";

When I update the user in the application and save it to the database using JSON_SET('column', 'name', 'value'). Everything works fine. Examples:

- `` UPDATE `users` SET `data` = JSON_SET(`data`, '$.lastname', 'lastname') WHERE `userid` = 1; ``
- `` UPDATE `users` SET `data` = JSON_SET(`data`, '$.money', 120) WHERE `userid` = 1; ``

But when I try to set for example a list or hashmap, things starting to get tricky. I use json-simple and gson to parse all objects to json before saving them to the database. But when I do this with a list or hashmap I cant set it in the database (unless I set parse the json to a string with '' around it)

But when I do add the '', json deserialize doesn't see it as a list.

Hope you guys can help me out. thanks in advance.

Here is some code:

```
String query = "UPDATE `users` SET `data` = JSON_SET(`data`, '$." + fieldName + "', " + this.gson.toJson(value) + ") WHERE `userid` = '" + userId + "';";
```